# struts 2 Bean does not populate in action class

Tags: struts2, javabeans

I am using Struts 2-Spring framework in my assignment.

I have defined a bean in struts 2 action class

One interceptor for checking authorisation before executing every action.

The bean is used for defining controls like textfield, Radio button, etc on jsp page.

On submit of this page control goes properly to defined action class, but finds bean object as null in action class. Hence unable to perform futher operations.

Removing interceptors works fine.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: It is always difficult to tell whats the problem without seeing code.

Comment: can you provides the struts.xml as it seems you are doing something wrong with the configuration

Comment: It sounds like you've reconfigured the action's interceptor stack but only defined yours, not an entire stack--as the other comments state, without any actual information, we're just guessing.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's true. I haven't defined entire stack. Its works after defining entire stack along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't defined stack for interceptors defined in struts.xml.

After defining below stack in struts.xml its works fine:

```
<interceptors>
<interceptor-stack name="applicationStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
      <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>

    <!-- User defined interceptor -->
    <interceptor-ref name="contextSecurityInterceptor"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```